# Standard deviation comparison for splitting clusters in ISODATA

Tags: clustering, data-mining, dataset, standard-deviation, extreme-value

I am currently implementing the ISODATA algorithm and I am new to cluster analysis as I just learnt about it. I got stuck at the step which I need to compute the standard deviation of each cluster, pick the maximum one and compare it with the standard deviation threshold parameter for splitting the clusters as it will involve dealing with multidimensional standard deviations.

Say I have a computed the standard deviation of 3 clusters of a 4-dimensional data i.e. the Fisher's Iris Data

For example: Cluster 1 standard deviations = [12.489, 15.222, 18.141, 10.111],       Cluster 2 standard deviations = [15.678, 23.558, 11.111, 15.131] and Cluster 3 standard deviations = [20.222, 29.671, 13.111, 12.531], with an initial standard deviation threshold parameter of THETA_S = 20.

So at this step of the ISODATA algorithm before the splitting is performed, it would compare if the maxstdDev > THETA_S. As my standard deviations from 3 clusters are all 4-dimensional where each dimension represents the value of each flower feature, i.e. sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width, I do not know how should I perform the comparison before splitting the cluster.

Would anyone be kind to assist me as I am not able to proceed before clearing my doubt on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but you should use each vector's max element to perform the comparison, i.e cluster 1 max standard deviation is 18.141,...